# UIPopoverPresentationController showing full screen modal popup always

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am trying to show a view controller as UIPopoverPresentationController below the button or in center of window. But it is always showing as full window modal popup.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MySecondViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Pop"];

    // present the controller
    // on iPad, this will be a Popover
    // on iPhone, this will be an action sheet
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UINavigationControllerOperationPop;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 230);
    // configure the Popover presentation controller
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popController.delegate = self;

    // in case we don't have a bar button as reference
    popController.sourceView = self.showPop;
    popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(384, -120, 280, 230);


-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code it is working

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pop"];

controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 230);
// configure the Popover presentation controller

controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
controller.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;


// in case we don't have a bar button as reference
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(384, -120, 280, 230);
//    controller.presentationController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i'm going to use bar button...it shows me tablewiew on fullscreen...what should i do...@Hassan Aftab

Comment: @SurajSukale, it might be too late for you, but perhaps somebody else can benefit from this comment. You should assign a delegate to controller.popoverPresentationController and in the delegate implement method `adaptivePresentationStyle(for: UIPresentationController)`, returning value `UIModalPresentationStyleNone`

Answer (score 2):

I have posted another question for the same question and i have resolved my issue. Here is the link of question:
[UIPopoverPresentationController is showing full screen modal on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257256/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-is-showing-full-screen-modal-on-iphone)

In ViewController.h Firstly make a property of UIPopoverPresenatationController.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIPopoverPresentationController *dateTimePopover8;
```

Then to show PopOverPresentationcontroller

```
    UINavigationController *destNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dateVC];
/*Here dateVC is controller you want to show in popover*/
                dateVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280,200);
                destNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
                _dateTimePopover8 = destNav.popoverPresentationController;
                _dateTimePopover8.delegate = self;
                _dateTimePopover8.sourceView = self.view;
                _dateTimePopover8.sourceRect = [sender frame];
                destNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
                destNav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
                [self presentViewController:destNav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You must have noticed that we are presenting View Controller instead of presenting popOver.So we have to hide this in new way also.It hides automatically when we click on screen.

```
-(void)hideIOS8PopOver
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

We have to implement the delegate of UIPopoverPresenatationController in implementation file.Write below delegate method in implementation file.

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle) adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController: (UIPresentationController * ) controller {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard this is very easy. Just control drag from the control that will trigger the action (say a UIBarButton or a normal button) to the storyboard view controller (if root view of Navigation controller, drag to the navigation controller). 
Select the segue and change the Kind in the attribute inspector to "Present Modally", presentation: Form sheet (if you want it to show at the centre), select the transition type you want (default is cool).

[image: Attribute Inspector screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As @Lukas1 mentioned above, you should conform UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate and implement adaptivePresentationStyle method (which is actually defined in `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` protocol, `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` parent class) and return `.none`
And here's implementation in Swift5 :

```
extension ViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
}
```